# Facebook Like button suddenly stopped working for certain pages yesterday

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The Like button on (some URLs of) a few of our Facebook apps suddenly (apparently) reset to zero yesterday (about 18? hours ago), and will no longer count.  That is, if you Like the URL, it shows 1 for a brief instant and then resets.

Sorry if this sounds like a familiar question, but I have literally spent hours checking all similar questions on here and the rest of the interweb, followed relevant suggestions, all to no avail.

The main thing is that the Like buttons *have* worked for days, weeks or months - depending on the app - and suddenly, they have stopped.

Each URL passes through the linter (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint) with no problems detected whatsoever - yes, the resultant page has a fb:app_id tag, has all the required og: tags, even has a canonical URL.

However, the generated 'Like button' at the bottom of the linter performs exactly the same way as it does on our site - it flicks to '1' briefly, then shows 'Error' and the help popup suggests I use the linter. ;-)

This is an example 'problem' URL:
http://apps.facebook.com/winningsmiles/likeit

If you run this through the linter, nothing appears to be amiss.  However, the 'Like button' does not work.

And if you click on the 'Graph URL' for the page (http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://apps.facebook.com/winningsmiles/likeit), you will notice that this URL had 50 'shares', i.e. likes, up to the point that it stopped working.  So it *did work*.

A couple of important sidelights:

- There is URL rewriting in place, to make the URL 'friendlier'.  If I lint the URL with the full filename - add '.aspx' to the URL above (*sorry, I don't have enough 'reputation' to post another URL* ;-) - then the 'Like button' *can* be successfully used; but of course, is not the same URL (graph id) to Facebook, so cannot absorb the count of the URL that we have been using up to now;
- The above URL is the 'Like' URL for the app itself.  There is user-posted content throughout the site, and Facebook users have the opportunity for liking each post.  The Like button associated with each post *is* working, e.g.:
  http://apps.facebook.com/winningsmiles/likeit/2/951
  Important to note that this uses exactly the same server page as the main 'Like', and produces identical HTML and og: tags, apart from og:url and canonical of course.

Just a few technical remarks about the app hosting environment...

- the apps are written in ASP.NET;
- the three apps that I have tested, where the main Like button has stopped working, all sit on the same physical domain (panasonic.communicates.to) and web server;
- the domain is not yet on https - that will happen before Oct 1, but I don't believe that should be a valid reason for it to fail now.

It seems like it's not the content that's the issue, but  certain URLs are suddenly actively being blocked from being Liked.

Comment: I noticed the same thing 5 minutes ago. For some buttons it claims that:


Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL hxxps://www.facebook.com/my_app_url from frame with URL hxxps://www.youtube.com/embed/YT_ID?rel=0&wmode=transparent. Domains, protocols and ports must match.